# Is there a built-in and concise way to define required properties for a given Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I have a few custom Gradle tasks that require certain properties to be passed to the script as CLI arguments (using `-P`). For example:

```
task example(type: Copy) {
  if (!hasProperty('foo')) {
      throw new GradleException("The [foo] property is required")
  }

  if (!hasProperty('bar')) {
      throw new GradleException("The [bar] property is required")
  }

  if (!hasProperty('baz')) {
      throw new GradleException("The [baz] property is required")
  }
}
```

Does Gradle provide a built-in and concise way to define such requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no build-in possibility to do so without conditional checks.

But you can do it easily with [net.saliman.properties](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.saliman.properties) plugin.

From [the plugin documentation](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin#properties-added-to-each-task):

> **requiredProperty**
>
> ```
> requiredProperty "somePropertyName"
> ```
>
> This method throws a MissingPropertyException if the named property is not defined.
>
> **requiredProperties**
>
> ```
> requiredProperties "property1", "property2", ...
> ```
>
> This method throws a MissingPropertyException if any of the named properties are not defined
>
> **recommendedProperty**
>
> ```
> recommendedProperty "somePropertyName", "default File Text"
> ```
>
> This method is handy when there are properties that have defaults somewhere else. For example, the build file might define it, or the application might be able to get it from a system file. It is most useful in alerting newer developers that something must be configured somewhere on their systems.
>
> The method checks to see if the given property is defined. If it is not, a warning message is displayed alerting the user that a default will be used, and if the defaultFile has been given, the message will include it so that the developer knows which file will be providing the default value.

Your task will look like:

```
task example(type: Copy) {
    requiredProperties "foo", "bar", "baz"
}
```